# Регулярное выражение для определения строки в квадратных скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Я пытаюсь использовать что-то вроде

```
public static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\[(.*?)\]");
public static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\[(\w)\]");
```

на что получаю:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Символ `\` используется в java для escape-последовательностей(тех самых `\b \t \n \f \r \" \'`, про которые говорит компилятор. Поэтому чтобы использовать именно его в строке, нужно выполнить экранирование:

```
public static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
public static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w)\\]");
```

Comment: Да это сработало, но теперь нужно подобно скобкам экранировать двойные кавычки. Здесь такой метод не срабатывает, потому что IDE считает кавычку концом строки и выдает оишбку. На это я отвечаю такой строчкой. 
 
    Pattern.compile("\\\\"+(char)34+"(.*?)"+"\\\\"+(char)34);

Она сработает? Или лучше такая строка 

    Pattern.compile("\\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\\"");

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\\"(.?)\\\"");` вполне адекватный вариант

Comment: Паттерн матрёшка :-) Эскейпов Эскейп Эскейпович.

Comment: Такие вопросы только свидетельствуют в пользу того, что regexp'ы зло оказавшееся в Java чисто по недосмотру!

Comment: вот за эти мысли мне бармалей и нравится =)

Comment: @igumnov, а квадратные скобки **внутри** строки (например, "заэскейпенные") допустимы ?

Вы какие строки (синтаксис Java ?) имеете ввиду ?

Comment: Нет там должны быть одно слово из строчных и прописных английских букв.

Answer (score 0):

Дублируйте слеш: "`\\[(.*?)\\]`"