# Invalid escape sequence (\x) в Java

Tags: java

Привет.

Мне необходимо вывести как текст следующую строку:

```
String hexstr = "\x00\x00\x00\x18\x66\x74\x79\x70\x33\x67\x70\x34\x00\x00\x03\x00\x33\x67\x70\x34\x33\x67\x70\x36\x00\x00\x00\x00";
```

Но Java ругается:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

Я понимаю, что он как экранирование воспринимает, но как вежливо попросить не делать этого, при всей его "заботе" обо мне и коде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дублируйте слэш. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/101750/java-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85) есть похожий вопрос.

Comment: Поторопился задать вопрос. Нашел уже ответ. Спасибо.